# Скрыть и показать кнопку добавления комментария

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

не сочтите за тупость, но я никак не могу понять, что я делаю неправильно, может кто-нибудь ткнуть пальцем?

1) При нажатии на кнопку 'Добавить комментарий', кнопка скрывается и появляется форма;
2) После ввода и отправки формы, форма скрывается, и появляется снова кнопка

```
$('.show-form').on('click', function(){
   var _this = $(this);
   _this.parent().find('form').css('display', 'block');
   _this.hide();
   return false;
})
$('.create-comment').on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var _this = $(this);
   $.post(
      '/answer/create-comment',
       $(_this).closest('form').serialize(),
       function(data){
          if($(_this).closest('.answerRow').find('.comments-wrapper').length === 0){
           $(_this).closest('.answerRow').append('<div></div>');
           }   

           if(data.result === true ){
              $(_this).closest('.answerRow').find('.comments-wrapper').append(data.content);              
             $(_this).closest('form').hide();
             $(_this).closest('.a').show();
             //$(_this).find('.addComment .show-form').show(); //как тут показать снова эту кнопку?
          }
       },
       'json'
    )
});
```

Тут обычный html

```
<div class="addComment">
   <a href="" class="show-form">Добавить комментарий</a>
   <form style="display: none;">
      <textarea name="text" placeholder="Введите текст вашего комментария..." rows="5">
      </textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="answerId">
      <button class="create-comment">Добавить комментарий</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
_this.closest('.addComment').find(".show-form").show();
```

Comment: <pre>
Гениально и просто, Спасибо!!! Я перепробовал кажется и это, и многое другое, но ничего не получилось, не знаю почему.


----> вставляет в конец комментария
$(_this).closest('.addComment').find(".show-form").show();

----> вставляет в начало комментария
_this.closest('.addComment').find(".show-form").show();

Но работают оба метода.

Comment: @ratatuy На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".